# Stoping or re registering orphaned tasks on mesos cluster

Tags: mesos, marathon

I am using marathon to deploy my application on mesos-cluster. Recently I experienced failover in my mesos-master and marathon. On restarting, master was able to identify running old tasks on slave but was not showing them in active tasks pane as marathon registered with new framework id. Is it somehow possible to stop these orphaned tasks when we restart mesos-master so that they can be redeployed using marathon ?

Comment: Are you running your Masters and Agents in Docker containers?

Comment: No. I am using mesos and agents to deploy my docker containers.

Comment: IMO real problem is that marathon registered with new famework id.

Comment: Ok... I had these issues sometimes when running a fully Dockerized setup on CoreOS

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to shutdown the old Marathon frameworkId and kill all of its tasks using the [`/teardown`](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/teardown/) endpoint on the Mesos master.

You use the endpoint by sending a POST request with the frameworkID in the body. For example:

```
curl -d 'frameworkId=#' -X POST localhost:5050/master/teardown
```

You can find the frameworkId of your old Marathon instance by using one of the master endpoints, such as [`/frameworks`](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/master/frameworks/). Be careful to use the frameworkId of the *old* Marathon instance, not the new one.

Comment: IMO this only would work if the framework is still running.

Comment: If the old framework isn't running any more (e.g., the framework disconnected and its `failover_timeout` has been exceeded), then all of its tasks should have been killed anyway. Marathon uses a `failover_timeout` of 1 week by default.

Comment: But what happens in the case if master failed sometime after old framework dies?? Is it possible to re-register old framework on new master instance??

Comment: @t2nand: If the master fails over after the old framework dies but before the `failover_timeout` has expired, the framework is allowed to reregister (using the old FrameworkId) on the new master at any time in the future. If the framework doesn't reregister, any tasks it was running will continue to run but will be orphaned. This behavior is a bug (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-4659) -- probably the right fix is to persist the list of connected and failed frameworks in the replicated log, so that the `failover_timeout` can be followed even when the master fails over.